# What Is My Fault With This WP_QUERY ? [ Pagination Problem ]

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, pagination

I did a photo gallery with custom post type. The pagination works correct but, if I click to a category, then it must show all photos of the category with pagination, but page 2 not found. You can test it.

http://test.onurunwebsitesi.com

Click to Tümünü Göster (Show All) button, and click to deneme (try) category button and click Daha Eski Fotoğraflar (Previous Photos), there are 3 photos (I didn't add the photos, just added photo titles), I'm listing photos posts_per_page=2, but page 2 not found. Sorry for my bad English. I need your help. I'm working with it for a long time. Thanks in advance. My codes:

archive-fotograf.php

```
<?php /** * Displays the Pagination in Custom loop * */?> 
<?php get_header(); ?> 
<?php $aranan= $_GET['s'];  
$kategorim = get_query_var('cat'); 
$catName = strtolower(get_cat_name($kategorim)); 
$myterm = get_term( $kategorim, 'fgaleri' );  
$myslug = $myterm->slug; ?> 
<div id="content"> 
<?php 
$temp = $wp_query; //save old query 
$wp_query= null; //clear $wp_query 
$rakam= 0; 
$wp_query = new WP_Query(); 
//The query 
global $query_string;  
parse_str( $query_string, $my_query_array );  
$paged = ( isset( $my_query_array['paged'] ) && !empty( $my_query_array['paged'] ) ) ? $my_query_array['paged'] : 1;  
$wp_query->query('posts_per_page=2&post_type=fotograf&s=' . $aranan . '&paged=' .     $paged . '&taxonomy=fgaleri&fgaleri=' . $myslug ); 
?> 
<div id="FGaleri_2"><div id="FGaleri_Ic"><div id="FGaleriBaslik">Fotoğraf Galerisi  
<form action="<?php echo get_bloginfo('wpurl'); ?>" id="searchformfoto" method="get" name="searchform"> 
<?php $args = array( 'taxonomy' => 'fgaleri', 'show_option_none' => 'Kategori Seç ve Ara', 'hierarchical' => 1 ); wp_dropdown_categories($args); ?> 
<div id="aramabolumufoto"> 
<input name="s" id="sfoto" type="text" value=""/> 
<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="fotograf" /> 
<input id="searchsubmitfoto" type="submit" value="Ara"/> 
</div> 
</form> 
</div> 
<div class="FGaleri_Ic_2"><?php while ($wp_query->have_posts()): $wp_query->the_post(); $rakam++;  
//The loop 
?> 
<div class="FGaleriItem2" style="<?php if ($rakam % 5 == 0 ) { ?>margin-right: 2px;<?php } ?>"> 
<?php 
$termargs=array('orderby' => 'count', 'order' => 'desc'); 
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID , 'fgaleri', $termargs ); 
$t = count($terms); 
if ($t>0) { ?> 
<div class="fkategori"> 
<?php $c = 0; 
foreach($terms as $term) { 
$c++; 
if ($c==$t)  
{  
echo '<a class="foto_kategori" href="'. home_url() . '/?cat=' . $term->term_id . '&s=' . $query_vars['s'] . '&post_type=fotograf" title="' . $term->name . '" ' . '>' . $term->name.'</a> '; 
} 
} ?> 
</div> 
<?php } ?> 
<div class="ResimUst"> 
<?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) { ?> 
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"> 
<?php $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) ); 
$url2 = get_bloginfo('template_directory') . "/timthumb.php?src=" . $url . "&amp;w=100&amp;h=100&amp;zc=1"; ?> 
<img src="<?php if(get_option('of_timthumb')=="true") { echo $url2; } else { echo $url; } ?>" alt="" title="" width="100" height="100" /> 
</a> 
<?php } ?> 
</div> 
<div class="ResimAlt"> 
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> 
</div> 
</div> 
<?php if (($rakam % 5 == 0 ) && ($rakam > 4)) { ?><div class="clearboth"></div><?php } ?> 
<?php endwhile; ?> 
</div> 
</div> 
</div> 
<div class="clearboth"></div> 
<?php if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi') ) {      
wp_pagenavi(); //function call for plugin pagination( wp pagenavi plugin) 
}else{ ?>      
<div id="navigasyon"> 
<span class="previous-entries"> 
<?php next_posts_link('« Daha Eski Fotoğraflar'); ?></span> 
<span class="next-entries"><?php previous_posts_link('Daha Yeni Fotoğraflar »'); ?></span> 
</div><?php } //endif 
$wp_query = null; //Reset the normal query 
$wp_query = $temp; //Restore the query 
?> 
</div><?php get_sidebar(); ?></div><?php get_footer(); ?>
```

functions.php

```
<?php
add_action( 'init', 'register_cpt_fotograf' ); 
function register_cpt_fotograf() { 
$labels = array( 
'name' => _x( 'Fotoğraflar', 'fotograf' ), 
'singular_name' => _x( 'Fotoğraf', 'fotograf' ), 
'add_new' => _x( 'Yeni Ekle', 'fotograf' ), 
'add_new_item' => _x( 'Yeni Fotoğraf Ekle', 'fotograf' ), 
'edit_item' => _x( 'Fotoğrafı Düzenle', 'fotograf' ), 
'new_item' => _x( 'Yeni Fotoğraf', 'fotograf' ), 
'view_item' => _x( 'Fotoğrafı Önizle', 'fotograf' ), 
'search_items' => _x( 'Fotoğraf Ara', 'fotograf' ), 
'not_found' => _x( 'Fotoğraf Bulunamadı', 'fotograf' ), 
'not_found_in_trash' => _x( 'Çöpte Fotoğraf Bulunamadı', 'fotograf' ), 
'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Ana Fotoğraf:', 'fotograf' ), 
'menu_name' => _x( 'Fotoğraflar', 'fotograf' ), 
); 
$args = array( 
'labels' => $labels, 
'hierarchical' => false, 
'supports' => array( 'title', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields', 'comments' ),
'public' => true, 
'show_ui' => true, 
'show_in_menu' => true, 
'show_in_nav_menus' => false, 
'publicly_queryable' => true, 
'exclude_from_search' => false, 
'has_archive' => true, 
'query_var' => true, 
'can_export' => true, 
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'fotograflar'),
'capability_type' => 'post' 
); 
register_post_type( 'fotograf', $args ); 
} 
register_taxonomy("fgaleri", "fotograf", array("hierarchical" => true, "label" => "Fotoğraf Kategorileri", "singular_label" => "Fotoğraf Kategorisi", 'show_ui' => true, 'show_tagcloud' => false, "rewrite" => array('slug'=>'fkat')));

add_filter( 'request', 'my_request_filter' );
function my_request_filter( $query_vars ) {
if( isset( $_GET['s'] ) && empty( $_GET['s'] ) ) {
$query_vars['s'] = " ";    
}
return $query_vars;
}

function limit_posts_per_archive_page() {   
if (is_post_type_archive()) { $limit = 2; } else { $limit = get_option('posts_per_page'); }     
set_query_var('posts_per_archive_page', $limit);
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'limit_posts_per_archive_page');

?>
```

Comment: Are you **sure** this topic hasn't been covered before? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%2Btaxonomy+%2Bpagination+%2Bcategory . . . . . Please, *use proper indentation* when pasting code, it makes the Question **much easier** to read. . . . And a suggestion for a debugging method: make a very simple `archive-fotograf.php` until you know it's working.

Comment: If you can try wp-pagenavi plugin, you can use Scribu tip for custom queries http://scribu.net/wordpress/wp-pagenavi/wpn-2-74.html

Comment: Thanks for answer, but nothing changed. :(

Comment: "but nothing changed" doesn't really help...

Comment: @kaiser Hi, can you help me?

Comment: "Hi, can you help me?" also is of no help. Please provide meaningfull errors, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did! My new codes:

```
<?php /** * Displays the Pagination in Custom loop * */?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php global $wp_query;
$aranan= $_GET['s']; 
$kategorim = intval($_GET['cat']);
$kateg1= $_GET['kategorisec'];
if (intval($kateg1)<0) { $kateg = ""; } else { $kateg = $kateg1; }
$myterm = get_term( $kategorim, 'fgaleri' ); 
global $myslug;
$myslug = $myterm->slug; ?>
<div id="content">
<?php $rakam= 0;
//The query
$wp_query->query( array( 'post_type' =>'fotograf', 's' => $aranan, 'paged' => $paged, 'taxonomy' => 'fgaleri', 'fgaleri' => $kateg ) );
//The loop
?><div id="FGaleri_2"><div id="FGaleri_Ic"><div id="FGaleriBaslik">Fotoğraf Galerisi     <form action="<?php echo get_bloginfo('wpurl'); ?>" id="searchformfoto" method="get" name="searchform">
<?php $args = array( 'walker'=> new SH_Walker_TaxonomyDropdown(), 'class' => 'postform', 'id' => 'kategorisec', 'name' => 'kategorisec', 'value'=>'slug', 'taxonomy' => 'fgaleri', 'show_option_none' => 'Kategori Seç ve Ara', 'hierarchical' => 1 ); wp_dropdown_categories($args); ?>
<div id="aramabolumufoto">
<input name="s" id="sfoto" type="text" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="fotograf" />
<input id="searchsubmitfoto" type="submit" value="Ara"/>
</div></form></div>
<div class="FGaleri_Ic_2">
<?php while ($wp_query->have_posts()): $wp_query->the_post(); $rakam++; ?>
<div class="FGaleriItem2" style="<?php if ($rakam % 5 == 0 ) { ?>margin-right: 2px;<?php } ?>">
<?php 
$termargs=array('orderby' => 'count', 'order' => 'desc');
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID , 'fgaleri', $termargs );
$t = count($terms);
if ($t>0) { ?>
<div class="fkategori">
<?php $c = 0;
foreach($terms as $term) {  
$c++;  
if ($c==$t)   
{   echo '<a class="foto_kategori" href="'. home_url() . '/?kategorisec=' . $term->slug . '&post_type=fotograf" title="' . $term->name . '" ' . '>' . $term->name.'</a> ';  }} ?>
</div><?php } ?>
<div class="ResimUst">
<?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
<?php $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );$url2 = get_bloginfo('template_directory') . "/timthumb.php?src=" . $url . "&amp;w=100&amp;h=100&amp;zc=1"; ?>
<img src="<?php if(get_option('of_timthumb')=="true") { echo $url2; } else { echo $url; } ?>" alt="" title="" width="100" height="100" /></a>
<?php } ?>
</div><div class="ResimAlt"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
<?php the_title(); ?>
</a></div></div>
<?php if (($rakam % 5 == 0 ) && ($rakam > 4)) { ?><div class="clearboth"></div><?php } ?>
<?php endwhile; ?></div></div></div><div class="clearboth"></div>
<?php if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi') ) {     
wp_pagenavi(); 
//function call for plugin pagination( wp pagenavi plugin)
} else { ?>     
<div id="navigasyon"><span class="previous-entries">
<?php next_posts_link('« Daha Eski Fotoğraflar'); ?></span>
<span class="next-entries"><?php previous_posts_link('Daha Yeni Fotoğraflar »'); ?></span>
</div><?php } //endif ?><?php ?></div><?php get_sidebar(); ?></div><?php get_footer(); ?>
```